# Django ORM, how to use values() and still work with choicefield?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, choicefield

I am using django v1.10.2

I am trying to create dynamic reports whereby I store fields and conditions and the main ORM model information into database.

My code for the generation of the dynamic report is

```
class_object = class_for_name("app.models", main_model_name)

results = (class_object.objects.filter(**conditions_dict)
                               .values(*display_columns)
                               .order_by(*sort_columns)
                               [:50])
```

So `main_model_name` can be anything.
This works great except that sometimes associated models of the `main_model` have `choicefield`.

So for one of the reports `main_model` is `Pallet`.
`Pallet` has many `PalletMovement`.
My display columns are :`serial_number`, `created_at`, `pallet_movement__location`

The first two columns are fields that belong to `Pallet` model.
The last one is from `PalletMovement`

What happens is that `PalletMovement` model looks like this:

```
class PalletMovement(models.Model):
    pallet = models.ForeignKey(Pallet, related_name='pallet_movements',
                               verbose_name=_('Pallet'))
    WAREHOUSE_CHOICES = (
        ('AB', 'AB-Delaware'),
        ('CD', 'CD-Delaware'),
    )
    location = models.CharField(choices=WAREHOUSE_CHOICES,
                                max_length=2,
                                default='AB',
                                verbose_name=_('Warehouse Location'))
```

Since the queryset will return me the raw values, how can I make use of the `choicefield` in `PalletMovement` model to ensure that the `pallet_movement__location` gives me the display of `AB-Delaware` or `CD-Delaware`?

Bear in mind that the `main_model` can be anything depending on what I store in the database.

Presumably, I can store more information in the database to help me do the filtering and presentation of data even better.

Comment: Hey, @KimStacks I was wondering, did you find any answer helpful?

Answer (score 4):

The `values()` method returns a dictionary of key-value pairs representing your field name and a corresponding value.

For example:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Query:

```
result = MyModel.objects.filter(surname='moutafis').values('name', 'surname')
```

Result:

```
< Queryset [{'name': 'moutafis', 'surname': 'john'}] >
```

You can now manipulate this result as you would a normal dictionary:

```
if main_model_name is 'PalletMovement':
    # Make life easier
    choices = dict(PalletMovement.WAREHOUSE_CHOICES)

    for item in result:
        item.update({ 
            pallet_movement__location: verbal_choice.get(
                pallet_movement__location, pallet_movement__location)
        })
```

You can even make this into a function for better re-usability:

```
def verbalize_choices(choices_dict, queryset, search_key):
    result = queryset        

    for item in result:
        item.update({ search_key: choices_dict.get(search_key, search_key) })

    return result

verbal_result = verbalize_choices(
                    dict(PalletMovement.WAREHOUSE_CHOICES),
                    result,
                    'pallet_movement__location'
                )
```

I suggest the use of the `update()` and `get()` methods because they will save you from potential errors, like:

- The `search_key` does not exist in the `choice_dict` then `get()` will return the value of the `search_key`
- `update()` will try to update the given key-value pair if exists, else it will add it to the dictionary.

---

If the usage of the above will be in the template representation of your data, you can create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) instead:

```
@register.filter(name='verbalize_choice')
def choice_to_verbal(choice):
    return dict(PalletMovement.WAREHOUSE_CHOICES)[choice]
```

Have an extra look here: [Django: How to access the display value of a ChoiceField in template given the actual value and the choices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424992/django-how-to-access-the-display-value-of-a-choicefield-in-template-given-the-a)

Answer (score 1):

You would use `get_foo_display`

In your template:

```
{{ obj.get_location_display }}
```

or

```
{{ obj.pallet_movement.get_location_display }}
```

[Edit:] As pointed out in the comments this will not work when calling `values()`

Comment: Note you can't use `get_foo_display` if you use `values()`.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative to create a templatetag is :

```
{{form.choicefield.1}}
```

This shows the value of the initial data of the foreign key field instead the id.

Answer (score 1):

The universal solution for any `main_model_name` is by Django [Model _meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/) introspection:  **`class_object._meta.get_field(field_name).choices`**
That is:

```
choice_dicts = {}
for field_name in display_columns:
    choice_dicts[field_name] = {
        k: v for k, v in class_object._meta.get_field(field_name).choices
    }
out = []
for row in results:
    out.append({name: choice_dicts[name].get(value, value)
                for name, value in row.items()
                })
```

---

The rest is a **trivial example**, mostly copied code from the question

```
>>> pallet = app.models.Pallet.objects.create()
>>> palletm = app.models.PalletMovement.objects.create(pallet=pallet, location='AB')
>>>
>>> main_model_name = 'PalletMovement'
>>> conditions_dict = {}
>>> display_columns = ['pallet_id', 'location']
>>> sort_columns = []
>>>
>>> class_object = class_for_name("app.models", main_model_name)
>>> results = (class_object.objects.filter(**conditions_dict)
...                                .values(*display_columns)
...                                .order_by(*sort_columns)
...            )[:50]
>>>
>>> # *** INSERT HERE ALL CODE THAT WAS ABOVE ***
>>>
>>> print(out)
[{'location': 'AB-Delaware', 'pallet_id': 1}]
```

It works equally with 'pallet_id' or with 'pallet' in `display_columns`. Even that "_meta" starts with underscore, it is a documented API.